# read_excel devuelve ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy leyendo un archivo xlsx que de antemano cada vez que intento abrirlo me salta la ventana con el mensaje:

*"Hemos encontrado un problema con contenido de "blabla.xlsx".¿Desea que intentemos recuperar el máximo de contenido posible? Si confía en el origen de este libro, haga click en Sí"*.

He intentado abrir el archivo con *pandas* de la siguiente manera:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_xlsx)
```

también traté de pasar las columnas como *str*:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_xlsx, dtype=str)
```

La salida por pantalla que obtengo siempre es la misma:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Sospecho que la columna en cuestión es una llamada "ExpDate"...
la misma contiene datos de este estilo :

```
NaN
NaN
NaN
31/12/2021
31/12/2021
NaN
```

Comment: Si la excel está corrupta mala solución veo. Yo probaría a exportar la hoja en formato .csv y leer ese desde pandas, que te dará menos problemas.

Comment: Es una tarea automatizada que ingresa al sitio, busca el reporte en cuestión, lo descarga y lo abre. Todo dentro del mismo script,  solo hago `element.click()` y no tengo la opción de elegir el formato del archivo